# Convert escape sequences the way a compiler would

Tags: c++, escaping

Here's the dup: [Convert string with explicit escape sequence into relative character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5612182/convert-string-with-explicit-escape-sequence-into-relative-character)

---

How do I write the `fixup()` function (below) to make the assertion pass?  I would like this to be generalized so that it can handle arbitrary strings which may contain any standard [escape sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape).

I'm hoping that there's a simple solution, using standard functions.

```
/*BINFMTCXX: -Wall -Werror
*/

   #include <string>
   #include <cassert>
   #include <iostream>
   using std::string; using std::cerr;

string fixup( string input ) { return input; }

int main()
   {
   string target="\101";
   string input="\\101";
   string actual=fixup(input);
   cerr<<"target=["<<target<<"], input=["<<input<<"], actual=["<<actual<<"]\n";
   assert( actual == target );
   }
```

Current output:

```
target=[A], input=[\101], actual=[\101]
int main(): Assertion `actual == target' failed.
```

Desired output:

```
target=[A], input=[\101], actual=[A]
```

Comment: You do know that "\n" is actually a string that consists of **one** character, not two?  If you want proof, print `target.size()`.  So how are you possibly going to process a character string that has size 1, thinking that it has a size of 2?  The escape sequences are used only for C++ source code, not for interpreting what you may get at runtime.  What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Yes, and `\\n` is two characters, which I want to convert to one.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of `target`, and it doesn't answer the real question -- what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: The actual problem is that I want the user to be able to provide `\n` as an input, and my program should treat that as a linefeed.  et cetera.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: I want a function that converts `input`, which in the example is two characters, to match `target`, which is one character.

Comment: What if the user enters "\\n"?  Is that a escape backslash followed by an "n", or is that a single slash followed by a "\n"?

Comment: It's relatively simple string parsing, until you get to \U####### stuff, then we get into multibyte vs. wide char.  Are you willing to forgo \U?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: Whatever a C++ compiler does with that is fine for this.

Comment: @Jfevold: I don't know.  That probably doesn't matter too much.  But I'm trying to avoid doing this manually.  I don't want the extra code.

Comment: This was closed as a dup of a question asking for the inverse operation.

Comment: I wonder how many downvotes I've earned just because people don't think my code is purty.